# {testthat} `quasi_label` with `expect_match` throws "Error: invalid argument type"

Tags: r, rlang, testthat, quasiquotes

I am new to {testthat} and am building tests for a function that modifies strings and is expected to produce a specific output for certain input patterns.

As a example (reprex below), `add_excitement` adds an exclamation point to its input string. When given an input of "hello" it should return "hello!"; when given any other input it should *not* return "hello!". I would like to {testthat} behavior on a series of patterns and return informative errors which specify which pattern caused the error.

Based on {testthat} package documentation, I believe I should use `expect_match`. However, this throws an "invalid argument type" error, whereas `expect_identical` works. I don't understand why this is happening. My questions are:

- Why does `expect_identical` and not `expect_match` accept the `quasi_label` argument?
- Could I use `expect_identical` rather than `expect_match` for my purposes, or does this risk other errors?

Here is a reprex:

```r
library(testthat)
library(purrr)

patterns = c("hello", "goodbye", "cheers")
add_excitement <- function(pattern) paste0(pattern, "!")

# For a single pattern
show_failure(expect_identical(add_excitement(!!patterns[2]), "hello!"))
#> Failed expectation:
#> add_excitement("goodbye") not identical to "hello!".
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> x[1]: "goodbye!"
#> y[1]: "hello!"
try(
  show_failure(expect_match(add_excitement(!!patterns[2]), "hello!", fixed = TRUE,all = TRUE))
)
#> Error in !patterns[2] : invalid argument type

# For multiple patterns
purrr::map(
  patterns, 
  ~ show_failure(expect_identical(add_excitement(!!.), "hello!"))
)
#> Failed expectation:
#> add_excitement("goodbye") not identical to "hello!".
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> x[1]: "goodbye!"
#> y[1]: "hello!"
#> Failed expectation:
#> add_excitement("cheers") not identical to "hello!".
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> x[1]: "cheers!"
#> y[1]: "hello!"
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL

try(
  purrr::map(
    patterns, 
    ~ show_failure(expect_match(add_excitement(!!.), "hello!", 
                                fixed = TRUE, all = TRUE)
    )
  )
)
#> Error in !. : invalid argument type
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem following https://r-pkgs.org/tests.html#building-your-own-testing-tools, which uses non-standard evaluation `bquote()` and `eval()` (instead of `quasi_label()`) to produce the more informative errors.

```r
library(testthat)
library(purrr)

patterns = c("hello", "goodbye", "cheers")
add_excitement <- function(pattern) paste0(pattern, "!")

show_failure(eval(bquote(expect_match(add_excitement(.(patterns[2])), "hello!", fixed = TRUE, all = TRUE))))
#> Failed expectation:
#> add_excitement("goodbye") does not match "hello!".
#> Actual value: "goodbye!"


purrr::walk(
  patterns,
  ~ show_failure(eval(bquote(expect_match(add_excitement(.(.)), "hello!", fixed = TRUE, all = TRUE))))
)
#> Failed expectation:
#> add_excitement("goodbye") does not match "hello!".
#> Actual value: "goodbye!"
#> Failed expectation:
#> add_excitement("cheers") does not match "hello!".
#> Actual value: "cheers!"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Or for a tidy version:

```r
library(testthat)
library(purrr)

patterns = c("hello", "goodbye", "cheers")
add_excitement <- function(pattern) paste0(pattern, "!")

expect_hello <- function(pattern) {
  show_failure(eval(bquote(expect_match(add_excitement(.(pattern)), "hello!", fixed = TRUE, all = TRUE))))
}

expect_hello(patterns[2])
#> Failed expectation:
#> add_excitement("goodbye") does not match "hello!".
#> Actual value: "goodbye!"

walk(patterns, expect_hello)
#> Failed expectation:
#> add_excitement("goodbye") does not match "hello!".
#> Actual value: "goodbye!"
#> Failed expectation:
#> add_excitement("cheers") does not match "hello!".
#> Actual value: "cheers!"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The error is linked to the use of [`tidyeval` bang bang `!!` operator](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/sec-why-how.html#quoting-code).
[This is superseded](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/index.html), and the example you provided works without :

```
show_failure(expect_identical(add_excitement(patterns[2]), "hello!"))

# Failed expectation:
# add_excitement(patterns[2]) not identical to "hello!".
# 1/1 mismatches
# x[1]: "goodbye!"
# y[1]: "hello!"

show_failure(expect_match(add_excitement(patterns[2]), "hello!", fixed = TRUE,all = TRUE))

# Failed expectation:
# add_excitement(patterns[2]) does not match "hello!".
# Actual value: "goodbye!"

purrr::map(
  patterns, 
  ~ show_failure(expect_match(add_excitement(.x), "hello!", 
                              fixed = TRUE, all = TRUE)
  )
)

Failed expectation:
add_excitement(.x) does not match "hello!".
Actual value: "goodbye!"
Failed expectation:
add_excitement(.x) does not match "hello!".
Actual value: "cheers!"
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. However the version without `tidyeval` doesn't show the `pattern` in the error.   `show_failure(expect_identical(add_excitement(!!patterns[2]), "hello!"))` gives `add_excitement("goodbye") not identical to "hello!".` but `show_failure(expect_identical(add_excitement(patterns[2]), "hello!"))` gives the less informative `add_excitement(patterns[2]) not identical to "hello!".`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and glad you found a solution!